# Choosing between Firebird and HSQLDB in Java

Tags: java, database, comparison, firebird, hsqldb

I want to write a small (5-6 table) desktop app in Java. I want to use Firebird 2.1. database. But I googled and see HSQLDB. I want to make a decision between Firebird and hsqldb.

So which database I have to use?

Comment: Why have you narrowed it down to those two?  Have you looked at Oracle, or MySQL?

Comment: I would go with Apache Derby. It is actually very well crafted, can be transactional if needed (although never tried), being written in Java is additional plus. Problems I've found it will not 'give back' taken disk space when you delete data in tables, once I was not able to fix one index..

Comment: +1 for Derby / Java DB, it is included in the Java SE Development Kit.

Comment: hsqldb's own claim on their site: its much more std sql compliant. has to be true.

Comment: This is primarily opinion based, and thus would be best placed on hold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a desktop application an embedded database should be enough. [hsqldb](http://hsqldb.org/) or [h2](http://www.h2database.com/) are very well suited for this. You just have to add the JAR file to you applications classpath. Firebird looks more complex.

Actually, [H2 is more advanced than hsqldb](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#comparison).

Comment: That list has been proven quite biased a couple of times (I'm following the various mailing lists of Derby, H2, HSQLDB). And it hides some facts, such as H2's missing support for typed arrays, missing support for a PL/SQL-like stored procedure language, incomplete `information_schema` implementation, less standards-compliant, etc. So "more advanced" might not hold true (anymore)

Comment: Be aware: H2 does not provide a stored procedure language but instead lets you do that in Java/JDBC.  It will be much more work to write JDBC than it is to write a stored procedure.  Also, the JDBC in H2 is not type and dependance checked like Firebird's stored procedure language so errors may not show until you run into them; your not prevented from deleting something where there is a dependency in a stored procedure.

Answer (score 6):

Firebird runs in a process of its own and your java app needs to communicate with it. The advantage HSQLDB has that it is written in java, and can run in the same process, which simplifies your installation and runtime check ups (Is the db running, connection errors, etc.). It can persist the data to the disk as well. AN additional option is the [H2 database](http://www.h2database.com/) db, which also can run in process.

I'd go with the HSQLDB or H2.

Comment: I think H2 is the successor to HSQLDB, original author's second pure java database ... appears to have way more features

Comment: Firebird Embedded runs in the same process too. With the advantage that if you need to scale the database later you can simply move it to a server.

Comment: Can Firebird Embedded run embedded in a Java application so that it runs in the java.exe process? AFAIK this is not the case.

Comment: @mjustin - no, it is run in a separate process

Comment: Then why firebird is far more popular in gitHub?

Answer (score 2):

I recomend HSQLDB because it's implemented in Java (so you have the same platform as the application) and I guess that you don't need any of the feature for the project of that size that could FireBird provide.

Answer (score 2):

Firebird is very good embedded database and just win an award at [SouceForge this year](http://sourceforge.net/community/cca09/)

SQLite have good press for embedded Database too.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that Java 6 comes with [JavaDB](http://developers.sun.com/javadb/), and that may be a useful implementation for a first solution. It's a repackaged [Apache Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/), and consequently quite powerful.

Comment: It is optional in the installation.