# What will be the best embedded database to be used with a small Java desktop application?

Tags: java, open-source, jpa, desktop-application, embedded-database

My requirements are

- Embedded Database
- Easy Integration with Netbeans IDE
- Should be able to develop using JPA
- Free of cost
- Size of the database should be minimum

Please do suggest me a database with the above mentioned features and some pointers to good tutorials regarding that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Embedded java databases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57102/embedded-java-databases)

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771962/100-pure-java-database-closed, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462923/java-embedded-databases-comparison, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431546/lightest-database-to-be-packed-with-an-application, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444265/simple-and-reliable-in-memory-database-for-fast-java-integration-tests-with-suppo, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187974/firebird-vs-hsqldb-at-java etc, etc, etc. Please do a search.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/). Looking at tutorials of frameworks like Spring and Hibernate, they tend to use HSQLDB as an example of how to use an embedded database with them.

You can use JPA with it, I've personally tried with Hibernate and have had some great results. It's used in projects such as OpenOffice and Mathematica, so that should speak of its quality.

HSQLDB fits 4 of your 5 requirements. Maybe 5 of 5, only because I don't use Netbeans as my IDE. But I'm sure you can try it yourself.

Comment: I'd recommend H2 database  as it's essentially the same as HSQLDB has way better performance and a GUI console app.

Answer (score 2):

[H2 database](http://www.h2database.com) is also a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

Try with apache derby
http://db.apache.org/derby/